# Select ALL Columns | Rows of a data.table based on condition

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Two related questions:

**EDIT:** *ps. I'm looking for solutions based on `data.table`.*

**1.** How to select the **rows** of `data.table` above a certain threshold for all columns?

**2.** How to select the **columns** of `data.table` which contain values above a certain threshold ?

Reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(V1=1:5, V2=3:7, V3=7:3)
```

#### conditionally selecting all rows

```
# this line selects rows based on column `V1`. 
  dt[ V1 > 2, ] 

# I'm looking for a way to select rows based on values of all columns. My failed attempt
  dt[ names(dt) > 2, ] 

# *expected output*: a data.table with all columns but only with those rows where all values are `> 2` 

#> V1 V2 V3
#> 3  5  5
#> 4  6  4
#> 5  7  3
```

#### conditionally selecting all columns

```
# My failed attempt
  dt[, .SD, .SDcols > 2 ]

# *expected output*: a data.table with all rows but only with those columns where all values are `> 2`

#>   V2 V3
#>   3  7
#>   4  6
#>   5  5
#>   6  4
#>   7  3
```

Comment: what's your expected output? what you wanna achieve is not clear to me.

Comment: I've added more info to the question. Is that enough ?

Comment: thank you it is clearer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting all columns but only rows where all values are superior to a treshold, the best way is to use classic filtering as:

```
dt[rowMeans(dt>threshold)==1,]
```

For getting all rows but only columns where all values are superior to a treshold, you can do:

```
dt[,colMeans(dt>threshold)==1, with=F]
```

Answer (score 1):

For subsetting rows, the following code uses base R.  Because you are looking across rows, you are treating the data table more like a matrix.

```
rws <- apply(dt, 1L, function(r) any(r > 4))
dt[rws]
```

For columns, you can use the list-like properties of the data table again:

```
cls <- sapply(dt, function(c) any(c > 4))
dt[, cls, with = FALSE]
```

Comment: Thank you @Bazz. I should have made it clear that I'm looking for solutions based on `data.table.` Your answer is helpful though and I'm sure some people will find it useful

Comment: Okay.  The conditional row subsetting seems to be more of a matrix operation.  I could do `mtcars[, .SD[apply(.SD > 4, 1L, any)], .SDcols = names(mtcars)]` which looks more like a `data.table` operation, but `mtcars > 4` or `.SD > 4` outputs a matrix.  Columns subsetting: `mtcars[, .SD[sapply(lapply(.SD, ">", 4), any)], .SDcols = names(mtcars)]` perhaps, but it's essentially the same as above.

Comment: I see now that you wanted "all" values > 4.  Substitute "all" for "any" in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, much more complex solution than `rowMeans` but gives more flexibility. Using `lhs.all` helper function to recycle expression for all fields in *LHS* of provided expression.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(V1=1:5, V2=3:7, V3=7:3)

lhs.all = function(pseudo.expr) {
    sub.pseudo.expr = substitute(pseudo.expr)
    stopifnot(is.call(sub.pseudo.expr), is.character(cols <- eval.parent(sub.pseudo.expr[[2L]])))
    l.expr = lapply(cols, function(x) {
        sub.expr=sub.pseudo.expr
        sub.expr[[2L]] = as.name(x)
        sub.expr
    })
    Reduce(function(a, b) bquote(.(a) & .(b)), l.expr)
}
lhs.all(names(dt) > 2)
#V1 > 2 & V2 > 2 & V3 > 2
dt[eval(lhs.all(names(dt) > 2))]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  3  5  5
#2:  4  6  4
#3:  5  7  3
```